# How to insert a block of code inside a file based on specific pattern in Linux

Tags: bash, sed, sh

I want to insert a block of code inside a file name build.gradle
This is the block of line:

```
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("$keystorefile")
            storePassword "$keystorepass"
            keyAlias "$keystorealias"
            keyPassword "$keystorepass"
        }
    }
```

I want to insert it after a word "compileSdkVersion"
I have tried this command:

```
sed -i '/compileSdkVersion/i \
    signingConfigs {\
        release {\
            storeFile file("$keystorefile")\
            storePassword "$keystorepass"\
            keyAlias "$keystorealias"\
            keyPassword "$keystorepass"\
        }\
    }\' app/build.gradle
```

It is able to insert the block of code into the file, but somehow there is \ at the end of the line.

```
    signingConfigs {\
        release {\
            storeFile file("$keystorefile")\
            storePassword "$keystorepass"\
            keyAlias "$keystorealias"\
            keyPassword "$keystorepass"\
        }\
    }
```

I would like to remove those \ at the end of the line. How to smartly insert those block of code into the file ?

Answer (score 0):

OMG, I miss the last \ at the end, and now it solved, with this:

```
sed -i '/compileSdkVersion/i \
    signingConfigs {\
        release {\
            storeFile file("$keystorefile")\
            storePassword "$keystorepass"\
            keyAlias "$keystorealias"\
            keyPassword "$keystorepass"\
        }\
    }\ \ ' app/build.gradle
```